# How to split merged Excel cells with Python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to split only the merged cells in Excel file (with multiple sheets) that are like:

[image: Original sheets]

**Please** note that there are partially/fully empty rows. These rows are not merged.

Using `openpyxl`, I found the merged cell ranges in each sheet with this code:

```
wb2 = load_workbook('Example.xlsx')  
sheets = wb2.sheetnames  ##['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
for i,sheet in enumerate(sheets):
    ws = wb2[sheets[i]]
    print(ws.merged_cell_ranges)
```

The print output:
`['B3:B9', 'B13:B14', 'A3:A9', 'A13:A14', 'B20:B22', 'A20:A22']`

`['B5:B9', 'A12:A14', 'B12:B14', 'A17:A18', 'B17:B18', 'A27:A28', 'B27:B28', 'A20:A22', 'B20:B22', 'A3:A4', 'B3:B4', 'A5:A9']`

Since I found the merged cell ranges, I need to split the ranges and fill in the corresponding rows like this:

[image: Desired Sheets]

How can I split like this using `openpyxl`? I am new to using this module. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the unmerge function. Example:

```
ws.unmerge_cells(start_row=2,start_column=1,end_row=2,end_column=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use unmerge_cells function, sheet.merged_cells.ranges will be modified， so don't use sheet.merged_cells.ranges in for loop.

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import range_boundaries

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'tmp.xlsx')

for st_name in wb.sheetnames:
    st = wb[st_name]
    mcr_coord_list = [mcr.coord for mcr in st.merged_cells.ranges]
    
    for mcr in mcr_coord_list:
        min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(mcr)
        top_left_cell_value = st.cell(row=min_row, column=min_col).value
        st.unmerge_cells(mcr)
        for row in st.iter_rows(min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row, max_col=max_col, max_row=max_row):
            for cell in row:
                cell.value = top_left_cell_value

wb.save('merged_tmp.xlsx')
```

Comment: i'm not exaggerating when i say: you have totally changed my life. thank you!